# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'val'

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I am making a json request and i want a specific div to appear if the result from the request is true.

Currently I am getting the error bellow , could you please help me with the solution ?

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or
>   method 'val'

p.s : I have checked through console that json returns correctly "true" and the issue is on success.

I am attaching the code bellow.

Script :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ComputerLocation').hide();
        $('#typeddl').on('change', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetItemTypeForm")',
                data: { itemTypeId: $('#typeddl').val() },
                success: function (result) {                 
                    if (result != null && result.val(this.Value) == 'true') {
                        $('#ComputerLocation').show();
                    };
                }
            });
         });
    });

</script>
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetItemTypeForm(int itemTypeId)
        {
            //pseudo code
            var data = from s in db.ItemTypes
                       where s.ItemTypeId == itemTypeId 
                       select new { Value = s.IsComputer };

            return Json(data);
        }
```

Comment: i think you missed spelled val, try to use value instead

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly :

When you try to get val() in this line

> (ifresult != null && result.val(this.Value) == 'true') {

you are assuming result has a function called val, but in json you cant send function  and you are trying to send this function `this.Value` and that really don't make any sense at all.

I assume you want to :

> if (result != null && result.val == 'true') {

and in this line also you are using `this` I think that might also be wrong. You should set this to another field before using in ajax callback.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ComputerLocation').hide();
        $('#typeddl').on('change', function () {
           var that = this; // now this is an jquery object
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetItemTypeForm")',
                data: { itemTypeId: $('#typeddl').val() },
                success: function (result) {                 
                    if (result != null && result.val ==  'true') { // maybe you want to check that.val()
                        $('#ComputerLocation').show();
                    };
                }
            });
         });
    });
```

Comment: "result" has object "Value" , so i want when "Value" is true to display the div.

Comment: so this should work ? maybe just write " if ( result != null && result.Value === true) ..

Comment: hmmm , i have not javascript error now but its not making the div appear although the Value is true !

Comment: what do you see when you debug? does $('#ComputerLocation').show() runs ?

Comment: where do you see if it runs ? I can see that json sends Value:true

Comment: I mean debug with chrome developer tools.

Comment: i am watching chrome developer tools but i am not sure where can i see if the .show runs. I can only see my post and that it returns 0: {Value:true}
Value: true

Comment: I mean you can debug from script tab of dev tools. and it should be result.Value === true in this case.

Comment: unable to attach to the process. Another debugger may be attached to the process... when i try to see the script console in ie

Comment: check your json and result. so you can make proper comprasion.